# Find the general solution.$ (1 − \sin x \cos x) y′ +\cos(x) y^2 - y + \sin x = 0$. Riccati. If a special solution $y_1 = \cos x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I figure out where I did a mistake to complete solving? OR my method is wrong ?

[image]

Comment: I could not add the other photo of my remaining answer!

Comment: Please do not post pictures, but do take the time to typeset your answer using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Moo Its cos(x)y2